# How to get Argument from custom alias in linux

Tags: linux, parameters, alias, ubuntu-16.04

I'm currently creating an alias in my .bash_aliases that will close an app based on name of app using kill, grep, ps, and awk. The code looks like this.
alias close='kill $(ps -A | grep $input | awk  "{print $1}")'. The problem is that the call to close doesnt take a paramater ex. close firefox. My question is there a way to pass a paramater to an alias? and if so how do i insert it where $input is. I've searched google religiously but cant seem to find anything that fits my needs.

Comment: aliases are obsolete.  Write a function.  Functions take parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution and here is the code.
alias close='pkill $1'